# Failed to send join request to master in Elasticsearch, Unknown NamedWriteable [org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaData$Custom][licenses]]

Tags: elasticsearch, elk

We have a long running single node ELK cluster running (master/data). I have decided to add additional data node. However Im getting the below error on the data node

```
30.X.XXX}{172.30.X.XXX:9300}{ml.enabled=true}], reason [RemoteTransportException[[master][172.30.X.XXX:9300][internal:discovery/zen/join]]; 
nested: IllegalStateException[failure when sending a validation request to node]; 
nested: RemoteTransportException[[data1][172.30.X.XXX:9300][internal:discovery/zen/join/validate]]; 
nested: IllegalArgumentException[Unknown NamedWriteable [org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaData$Custom][licenses]]; ]
```

Below are the config files on master and new data node

Master Node:

```
cluster.name: my-application
node.name: master
node.master: true
node.data: true
path.data: /opt/elasticsearch
network.host: ["172.30.X.XX1","localhost"]
http.port: 9200
transport.tcp.port: 9300
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["172.30.X.XX1"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
```

Data1 Node:

```
cluster.name: my-application
node.name: data1
node.master: false
node.data: true
path.data: /opt/elasticsearch
network.host: ["172.30.X.XX2","localhost"]
http.port: 9200
transport.tcp.port: 9300
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["172.30.X.XX1"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
```

Tried pinging and checked telnet on 9200 and 9300 from master to data node and vice versa and it is working fine

I have tried deleting the data from /var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0 and restarted the data1, it didnt work

Comment: I'm a bit suspicious of the `licenses` in your log output. Are you sure this is the same version and package (OSS or basic) of the binary?

Answer (score 2):

This happens if you try with a mix of xpack/commercial/non-open-source binaries of Elasticsearch and some nodes with the open-source binaries.
Unfortunately Elasticsearch tries to "trick" you into using their non-open-source version nowadays and this causes many unintended non-open-source installations.

A simple solution is to install the non-oss version everywhere, however you may not want to run the commercial version as you then need to adhere to the commercial license!

In order to convert to the open-source license on all nodes you can do the following:

You can set the following in /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml and restart all nodes to disable some commercial features:

```
xpack.security.enabled: false
xpack.ml.enabled: false
```

Then you can change all nodes to the open-source binaries one by one in rolling fashion.

See also the following similar discussions:

- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-cluster-cant-join-new-node/126964
- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/adding-a-new-node-on-a-different-subnet/125377/2- https://github.com/codelibs/elasticsearch-module/issues/3
- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/transport-client-error-after-installing-x-pack-on-es-5-5-1/97021/4
- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/bulk-indexing-with-x-pack-exception/92086/5

Comment: thank you so much. After I upgrade all nodes it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error. There were multiple versions of Elasticsearch because of rolling upgrade. After upgrade all nodes and run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` the error fixed.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Message not fully read (response) for requestId [], handler [org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$ContextRestoreResponseHandler/org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4/[indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]:org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchTransportService$ConnectionCountingHandler@7518541f/org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchExecutionStatsCollector/org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction$1@cd2eb6d], error [false]; resetting
```